# Adding event listeners to multiple elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

What I am trying to do is target all the a tags within #menu-wrap li's.
I'm fairly new to JS so I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious!

JavaScript:

```
var menuLink = document.querySelector( '#menu-wrap li' );    
for (var i = 0; i < menuLink.children.length; i++) {
var childElement = menuLink.children[i];
childElement.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
}

function doSomething() {
    alert("Hello");
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu-wrap" id="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul id="menu-mobile-menu" class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>              
</div>
```

Comment: a better way: you can use one event on the <UL> instead of many events on the <LI>s. it's called _delegation_, look into it before you learn the harder-old-fashioned way of explicit manual subscription.

Comment: @dandavis, do you have a good reference about event delegation in raw javascript? I have already used the `jQuery.on` and interested to know the other way. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> Returns **the first element** within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes|by first element in document markup and iterating through sequential nodes by order of amount of child nodes) that matches the specified group of selectors.

You want to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and then loop over the resulting node list (or you want to bind your event handler to `#menu-wrap` itself and then use `event.target` to determine which list item was clicked on).

List items are not designed to be interactive controls. You should use a link or button instead.

Comment: + one, also for the last advice because robots semantically consider <li> to be list items and not links.

Comment: More to the point, users of linear navigation devices (i.e. those who don't use a mouse / trackpad / etc, such as many screen reader users), can't focus the elements in order to activate them.

Comment: yes true! thank you. could you just please intervene on Rando Hinn answer (someone downvoted it without explaining while it is working for me here on jsfiddle). What are reasons of it nor being the appropriate approach? Thanks again for your usual sharing

Answer (score -1):

`Document.querySelector` gets the first element only. But you can do this with classes. Do this. Just attatch class `sth` to anything you want to have the function.

HTML

```
<div class="menu-wrap" id="menu-wrap">
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul id="menu-mobile-menu" class="menu">
                    <li class="sth"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li class="sth"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li class="sth"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
</div>
```

JS

```
var menuLink = document.getElementsByClassName("sth");
for(var i = 0; i <  menuLink.length; i++ ) {
    var childElement = menuLink[i];
    childElement.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
}

function doSomething() {
    alert("Hello");
}
```

Comment: This annswer has been downvoted without explanation from downvoter, while I need as a newbie to know what is the reason behind choosing `querySelectorAll` insteal of `class` attribute.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711536/document-getelementsbyclassnamesth-vs-document-queryselectorallid-tagname