# document.getElementsByClassName("sth") vs document.querySelectorAll("#id tagname")

Tags: javascript, html

Given the following HTML:

```
   <ul id="menu-mobile" >
            <li class="menu"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
   </ul>
```

How to target all the `<li>`s in the best approach? is it by using the class name or by the id with `querySelectorAll()`?

```
var menuLink = document.querySelectorAll( '#menu-mobile li' );    
for (var i = 0; i < menuLink.children.length; i++) {
var childElement = menuLink.children[i];
childElement.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
}

function doSomething() {
    alert("Hello");
}
```

and

```
var menuLink = document.getElementsByClassName( 'menu' );    
for (var i = 0; i < menuLink.children.length; i++) {
var childElement = menuLink.children[i];
childElement.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
}

function doSomething() {
    alert("Hello");
}
```

both work.

Thanks

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is nice if you need to monitor a dynamic set of elements as it's a live collection, but that's actually rare and it's not hard to fire off another `querySelectorAll` when you need access to the collection. in short, there's a small/rare optimal use case for `getElementsByClassName`, everything else should be using `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @dandavis, I see, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` doesn't require that you block your markup by adding a class to every element in the list (and is supported by IE8).

Answer (score 1):

It depends. `getElementsByClassName` is [much faster](https://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall) and this fact could be useful if you need max performance. `querySelectorAll` is more developer-friendly in case of complex queries to DOM.

Comment: That test doesn't reflect the code in the question. It uses an attribute selector, which the question does not.

Comment: i don't think the execution speed matters because you shouldn't be calling either one very often, and if you are, then caching will be faster than either. you also need to keep in mind the hidden costs of live collections (like from getElementsByClassName). that collection is updating whether it needs to or not, and anytime something is inserted into the dom, that collection becomes dirty and needs to be rebuilt before using.

Comment: @Quentin: that's what i thought too, but on other tests, using the ".class" doesn't seem to be much faster than the attrib. i would guess that one gets converted to the other internally anyway...

Comment: i bet that if there's a same-shape live collection already, getElementsByClassName() makes a pointer to the orig copy instead of re-scanning the dom.